# Live logs on ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

How can I see live logs in Apache ActiveMQ installed on RHEL server?

I have enabled the logging feature by doing the following:

I went inside `/web/servers/apache-activemq-5.15.8/conf` location and edited the `log4j.properties` file and then uncommented this line:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=DEBUG
```

On the ActiveMQ version installed on Windows I usually start it from the command line so that shows live logs like connection related issues. However, on RHEL I am not sure how to get live logs. In Tomcat I could run `tail -f catalina.out` inside `logs` folder. Is there an equivalent of same thing in ActiveMQ?

The following is my `log4j.properties` file in case needed.

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
## contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
## this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
## The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
## (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
## the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
##
## http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
##
## Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
## distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
## WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
## See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
## limitations under the License.
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#
# This file controls most of the logging in ActiveMQ which is mainly based around
# the commons logging API.
#
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, logfile
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.spring=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.web.handler=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.xbean=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=INFO
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN

# When debugging or reporting problems to the ActiveMQ team,
# comment out the above lines and uncomment the next.

#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, logfile, console

# Or for more fine grained debug logging uncomment one of these
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=DEBUG

# Console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p | %m%n
log4j.appender.console.threshold=INFO

# File appender
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.file=${activemq.data}/activemq.log
log4j.appender.logfile.maxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.logfile.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.logfile.append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d | %-5p | %m | %c | %t%n
# use some of the following patterns to see MDC logging data
#
# %X{activemq.broker}
# %X{activemq.connector}
# %X{activemq.destination}
#
# e.g.
#
# log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d | %-20.20X{activemq.connector} | %-5p | %m | %c | %t%n

log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer

###########
# Audit log
###########

log4j.additivity.org.apache.activemq.audit=false
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.audit=INFO, audit

log4j.appender.audit=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.audit.file=${activemq.data}/audit.log
log4j.appender.audit.maxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.audit.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.audit.append=true
log4j.appender.audit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.audit.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p | %m | %t%n
```

When I did `tail -f activemq.log` I saw the the screen scrolling down constantly, and it shows some of the commands as I mentioned. So the console doesn't look like a stable one even though there isn't any thing going on with ActiveMQ right now from my end. The constant scrolling did stop after a while. This is some of the content I received:

```
2020-07-16 19:48:52,391 | DEBUG | WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check. | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer
2020-07-16 19:48:52,391 | DEBUG | Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:54567] | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker
2020-07-16 19:48:54,648 | DEBUG | WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check. | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer
2020-07-16 19:48:54,649 | DEBUG | Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:58331] | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker
2020-07-16 19:48:55,159 | DEBUG | queue://MessageProducerJMSV1 expiring messages .. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[Ubrite_ActiveMQ] Scheduler
2020-07-16 19:48:55,159 | DEBUG | queue://MessageProducerJMSV1, subscriptions=1, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, force:true, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 6, dequeueCount: 6, memUsage:0, maxPageSize:400 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[Ubrite_ActiveMQ] Scheduler
2020-07-16 19:48:55,160 | DEBUG | queue://MessageProducerJMSV1 expiring messages done. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[Ubrite_ActiveMQ] Scheduler
2020-07-16 19:48:55,160 | DEBUG | queue://MessageProducerJMSV1, subscriptions=1, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, force:false, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 6, dequeueCount: 6, memUsage:0, maxPageSize:200 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ BrokerService[Ubrite_ActiveMQ] Task-105
2020-07-16 19:48:56,267 | DEBUG | 30000ms elapsed since last read check. | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor ReadCheckTimer
2020-07-16 19:48:56,473 | DEBUG | WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check. | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer
2020-07-16 19:48:56,474 | DEBUG | Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:56897] | org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker
2020-07-16 19:48:56,634 | DEBUG | Checkpoint started. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker
2020-07-16 19:48:56,634 | DEBUG | Checkpoint done. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker
2020-07-16 19:48:57,104 | DEBUG | Job Scheduler Store Checkpoint started. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.scheduler.JobSchedulerStoreImpl | ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worke
```

Pasting Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use `tail -f activemq.log` where RHEL stores the ActiveMQ log files?

Comment: @JustinBertram When I did that I saw the the screen scrolling down constantly. And it shows some of the commands as I mentioned in the edited post above. So the console doesn't look like a stable one even though there isn't any thing going on with ActiveMQ right now from my end. Please take a look at the updated post with snippet copied from the live logs.

Comment: And the constant scrolling did stop after a while. So I pasted the screenshot in my post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tail -f activemq.log` is a good way to see the "live" logs from ActiveMQ.

The reason you're seeing *so* much logging is that you uncommented this line:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=DEBUG
```

This enabled *debug* logging for most of the broker's classes. Debug logging is mainly meant for developers or administrators who are closely familiar with internal broker operations and are trying to diagnose a problem. That's why the logging is so verbose.

Also, keep in mind that the broker has threads constantly running in the background performing various internal tasks. These threads may log debugging information. Therefore, even though no clients are interacting directly with the broker you can still see debug logging. This is not directly tied to the stability of the broker.

If you comment that line back out then the amount of logging will be greatly reduced and will almost certainly look more like what you're accustomed to seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I am a developer. However, I would try to turn it off and then see how it looks.

Comment: If you're not closely familiar with internal broker operations and trying to diagnose a problem then debug logging is not really useful.